# React Native module not found

Tags: ios, react-native

I get the following error in my ios simulator

```
Unable to resolve module react-native from / Users/myname/source/sandbox/auth/src/components/LoginForm.js: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
/Users/myname/source/sandbox/auth/node_modules
```

I went ahead and followed the directions for clear watchman as stated. Closed out my terminal, restarted my computer.

I researched on here and other sources. Found one work around to install an older version of firebase. I installed version@2.4.2 same error came up.

Here's my app component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Header } from './components/common';
import { LoginForm } from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "myApiKey",
    authDomain: "myDomain",
    databaseURL: "myURL",
    storageBucket: "myStorageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "myMessengerID"
    });
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header headerText="Authentication" />
        <LoginForm />
      </View>

    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

LoginForm component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-natvie';
import { Button, Card, CardSection } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection />
        <CardSection />
        <CardSection>
          <Button>
            Log In
          </Button>
        </CardSection>        
      </Card>
    );   
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see how is this related to firebase. Did you correctly setup your react-native project? Does the `node_modules/react-native` folder exists?

Comment: Yes, I do have the node_modules/react-native folder

Comment: Oh, the problem is in the `LoginForm` module, show us the code for that.

Comment: Okay will, do! Thanks Eldelshell

Comment: 'react-natvie' ???

Comment: Geez! mispelling. Great catch! Thanks, Eldelshell

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled `react-native` import in the beginning of your `LoginForm` component.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove curly braces around LoginForm during import.